# Flutter: LateInitializationError after resizing of the widget

Tags: flutter

I get a `LateInitializationError` on `items_head` after resizing my widget.

This is code:

```
class Head_View extends StatefulWidget {
  Head_View({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  late List<AppointmentItemWrapper> items_head;
  //late MultiChildRenderObjectWidget DTIT_head; --> **EDIT ON 20230605**
  @override
  State<Head_View> createState() => _Head_ViewState();
}

class _Head_ViewState extends State<Head_View> {
  @override
  void initState() {

    widget.items_head = [
      AppointmentItemWrapper(
        ID: 111,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        startDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 00, 0),
        endDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 30,0),
        position: 0,
        text: "Event N1",
        positiondragging: (double valxx) { print("HAHAH"); },
      ),
    ];

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DynamicTimeline(
      key: _myWidgetKey_DTIT_head,
      firstDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1,7,0,0),
      lastDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1,18,0,0),
      labelBuilder: DateFormat('hh:mm').format,
      items: widget.items_head, );
  }
}
```

As I thought:

`initState()` should be normally only called before first build (first build would happen in `super.init()`? )and when resizing the widget, `build` should be called again to rebuild the widget, but the `items_head` should be already in scope or am I wrong?

Comment: you have two `late` variables. and seconds one is not initialized

Comment: @SujanGainju: Thanks, I forget to delete this (I edited the question info) - I have forgotten to mention that `LateInitializationError` is on `items_head`

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the variables in the state widget when using the stateful widget type.

Move the `items_head` below to the `state` widget.

```
class Head_View extends StatefulWidget {
  Head_View({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Head_View> createState() => _Head_ViewState();
}

class _Head_ViewState extends State<Head_View> {
  
  late List<AppointmentItemWrapper> items_head;

@override
  void initState() {

    items_head = [
      AppointmentItemWrapper(
        ID: 111,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        startDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 00, 0),
        endDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 30,0),
        position: 0,
        text: "Event N1",
        positiondragging: (double valxx) { print("HAHAH"); },
      ),
    ];

    super.initState();
  }

....
```

Answer (score 0):

if you declare `items_head` in `class Head_View extends StatefulWidget {`

it will empty the List every time it rebuild.

try to declare here.

```
class _Head_ViewState extends State<Head_View> {

  late List<AppointmentItemWrapper> items_head;// **in here**

  @override
  void initState() {

    widget.items_head = [
      AppointmentItemWrapper(
        ID: 111,
        key: UniqueKey(),
        startDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 00, 0),
        endDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 9, 30,0),
        position: 0,
        text: "Event N1",
        positiondragging: (double valxx) { print("HAHAH"); },
      ),
    ];

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DynamicTimeline(
      key: _myWidgetKey_DTIT_head,
      firstDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1,7,0,0),
      lastDateTime: DateTime(2022, 1, 1,18,0,0),
      labelBuilder: DateFormat('hh:mm').format,
      items: widget.items_head, );
  }
}
```